# Are "so" and "so that" both acceptable here

Tags: conjunctions

> She hid the presents **so** the children wouldn't find them.
>
> She hid the presents **so that** the children wouldn't find them.

What I want to ask is whether both of the sentences above make sense (though different senses). To be clear, are "so" and "so that" both suitable to connect the clauses without any awkwardness?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15285/are-so-and-so-that-interchangeable)

Comment: Personally I think 'so that' is correct. I can't say that 'so' is not correct, but it seems to be weaker logically. Probably a formality thing as suggested by Sue and J.R. below

Answer (score 1):

Both *so* and *so that* work fine. The meaning is the same. I always think that putting the 'that' in makes it a bit more formal and therefore good in academic writing.

Comment: The two are the same in meaning? I thought "so that" means "in order that", showing the purpose while "so" indicates a result. Or maybe not? I'm a bit confused now :((